# Django SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT breaks unit tests that use the in-built client

Tags: django, unit-testing, ssl, django-rest-framework

I am working on a project that already has hundreds of unit tests, many of which use either the built in django Client, or the django rest framework APIClient for making requests and testing responses.

Having recently implemented the necessaries to make SSL work locally, and setting the `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to True (trying to make our dockerised `dev` and `test` environments as close to `production` as *possible*), I have come a cropper to find that so many unit tests fail, due to the (API)Clients requesting, by default, always using http, not https.

Many (most) requests look like this:

```
response = self.client.get(some_url)
```

I am aware that I could use:

```
response = self.client.get(some_url, secure=True)
```

But this does mean changing *a lot* of unit tests.  The same is true for using `follow=True`, but had the added disadvantage that this could produce some other undesired behaviour.

I cannot see a way of setting the use of secure requests as a default behaviour in the Django Client.  I could make my own SecureClient (and SecureAPIClient), but I would then have to make sure that I make a new base TestCase (possibly multiple) to inherit from, and change this everywhere for all the tests - still a lot of work.

It is possible of course to monkey patch the Client, but I am reluctant to to do this as, again, it could have undesired effects that are hard to debug later.

TLDR; Is there a simple (ideally supported) way, to make all unit test requests via the django test's Client, to use SSL by default?

Answer (score 10):

- Option 1. Disable the `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` when needed:

  ```
  from django.test import override_settings

  class FooTest(TestCase):

      def setUp(self):
          settings_manager = override_settings(SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False)
          settings_manager.enable()
          self.addCleanup(settings_manager.disable)
  ```
- Option 2: Wrap `get` and `post` methods of the `APIClient`:

  ```
  class ApiTestCase(TestCase):
      def setUp(self):
          self.client = APIClient()

      def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
          return self.client.get(secure=True, *args, **kwargs)

      def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
          return self.client.post(secure=True, *args, **kwargs)
  ```
- Option 3: just maintain a separate settings file for the test environment with the `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` not being set.

I've tried all three options and recommend going with the (3). Here is why:

1. `django.test.client` is just an imitation of a real client. It's there to unit test your views. It doesn't produce real WSGI requests, so test environment won't match production environment anyway.
2. `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` is a `SecurityMiddleware` setting. [Don't unit test third-party code](https://coderwall.com/p/45wycg/don-t-unit-test-third-party-code).
3. Making sure that your code always uses SSL is a good goal. However, this is an *integration* testing problem. The right tool for this job is [Selenium + LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `pytest` and `pytest-django`, you can also make a fixture that modifies the test client:

```
import functools
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def client(client):
    client.get = functools.partial(client.get, secure=True)
    client.post = functools.partial(client.post, secure=True)
    return client
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting problem and the way I solved it without changing existing unit tests was to modify manage.py to set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False` when running tests.

You can simply import

`from django.conf import settings`

in manage.py
and add

```
    # Disable HTTPS redirects while testing with Django's HTTP test client.
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "test":
        settings.SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
```

before

```
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```