# Getting a 301 instead of 200 on my production environment because of a redirect from '/' to 'https://testserver/'

Tags: django, http-status-code-301, django-testing, django-tests

I have the following test on my home page :

```
def test_homepage_is_available(self):
    url = reverse('home')
    response = self.client.get(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

On my dev server, this works fine and the test passes.

On my production server, I get an error. The `response.status_code` is 301.

The `url` from `reverse('home')` is `/`.

The `response['location']` is `https://testserver/`.

And so it looks like Django is redirecting from `/` to `https://testserver/`.

But why? And why does only do it on my production server? How can I fix this error?

---

Edit: here are my `urls.py` files as requested by commenters:

**main urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^', include('shop.urls')),
]
```

**shop.urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^$', views.Home.as_view(), name='shop__home'),
]
```

Comment: Please share your `urls.py` and the view that this url routes to.

Comment: Why are you running tests in production?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, just as a health check. These tests work on my dev environment.

Comment: @LeviPayne I added the relevant parts of `urls.py`, as per your request!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` in production, so Django is redirecting you to https.

You can prevent the redirect by using `secure=True`

```
response = self.client.get(url, secure=True)
```

If you don't want to change all your tests in this way, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626899/django-secure-ssl-redirect-breaks-unit-tests-that-use-the-in-built-client) for a discussion of different options.

Comment: Hi Alasdair, and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I had thought of this and had disabled `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to see if it fixed my issue. I tried your solution as well, but it has not fixed my issue. I don't think its HTTPS-related unfortunately :(