# Django Pytest Failing In GitHub Workflow - How to mimic production environment?

Tags: django, github-actions

I'm using GitHub Actions to create a CI/CD pipeline that tests production settings before deploying.

The tests pass in my local environment, and all of the code works in production. However, any tests related to views fail in my GitHub workflow. I believe the tests are failing because GitHub's `testserver` defaults to `http` protocol, I assume. And I have `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` in my production settings.

**Errors:**

```
_________________________ test_register_user_view_get __________________________

client = <django.test.client.Client object at 0x7fa8101e9e10>

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_register_user_view_get(client):
        response = client.get(reverse("accounts:register"))
>       assert 200 == response.status_code
E       assert 200 == 301
E        +  where 301 = <HttpResponsePermanentRedirect status_code=301, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="https://testserver/account/register/">.status_code

accounts/tests/test_views.py:11: AssertionError
_________________________ test_register_user_view_post _________________________

client = <django.test.client.Client object at 0x7fa80f8b2650>
django_user_model = <class 'accounts.models.User'>

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_register_user_view_post(client, django_user_model):
        response = client.post(
            reverse("accounts:register"),
            data={
                "username": "PostTest",
                "first_name": "User",
                "last_name": "Name",
                "email": "user@email.com",
                "password1": "zxceefF1238",
                "password2": "zxceefF1238",
            },
            follow=True,
        )
    
        assert 200 == response.status_code
>       assert django_user_model.objects.count() == 1
E       AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
E        +  where 0 = <bound method BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method of <django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager object at 0x7fa810f1b910>>()
E        +    where <bound method BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method of <django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager object at 0x7fa810f1b910>> = <django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager object at 0x7fa810f1b910>.count
E        +      where <django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager object at 0x7fa810f1b910> = <class 'accounts.models.User'>.objects

accounts/tests/test_views.py:30: AssertionError
```

When changing: `response = client.get(reverse("accounts:register"))`
to:

`response = client.get(reverse("accounts:register"), follow=True)`
The test will pass (for `test_register_user_view_get`), which is why I believe it's a protocol issue.

Can I tell GitHub which protocol to use, or is the issue entirely different?

```
name: CI

on:
    pull_request:
        branches: [main, main-dev]

jobs:
  production_build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:15
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: user
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: temp38383810
          POSTGRES_DB: db
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready 
          --health-interval 10s 
          --health-timeout 5s 
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
           python-version: 3.10.4
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run tests
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: "postgres://user:temp38383810@localhost:5432/db"
          DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "app.production_settings"
          DEBUG: "0"
          DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.DJANGO_SECRET_KEY }}
          CDN_ACCESS: ${{ secrets.CDN_ACCESS }}
          CDN_SECRET: ${{ secrets.CDN_SECRET }}
          EMAIL_HOST: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST }}
          EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD }}
          EMAIL_HOST_USER: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_USER }}
          RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: ${{ secrets.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}
          STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET: ${{ secrets.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET }}
        run: |
          python manage.py migrate
          python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
          pytest accounts -v
          pytest blog -v
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django SECURE\_SSL\_REDIRECT breaks unit tests that use the in-built client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626899/django-secure-ssl-redirect-breaks-unit-tests-that-use-the-in-built-client)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53143320/getting-a-301-instead-of-200-on-my-production-environment-because-of-a-redirect

Comment: @Azeem What I mean is the protocol is what's causing the 301. But at any rate, the tests related to post requests already have `follow=True` and still fail.

Comment: @user3605767: Got your point. I believe that the above attached threads explain it better how to approach this.